# Which design patterns (ideas) are suitable for a production line planning?

Tags: design-patterns, c#-4.0

I have a project (will be written in c#) in which i need to manage and monitor a production line.

The production line is consisted of several stations and a robotic arm.
The robotic arm moves a product from one station to the other.
Each station has a specific time limitations in which the product goes through a certain process (e.g. drying) and needs to be moved to the next station.

There is a constant stream of products so that all station are used to full capacity (except for the beginning and the end of the entire operation of the machine).

Edit:

I have a single robot with 6 stations around (!) it. The product is held by a rack that enters the machine in a constant rate of 10 minutes per rack. i attached an illustration of the machine.

The implementation i thought about was:

1. Predefine all the robot movement from one station to the other.
2. Create a task list in which each task stands for robot movement of a product that is performed if needed. this is quite a large list.
3. On each cycle check on the task list what needs to be done in the current time slice and execute if needed.

This is a quite basic and simple description of the machine.

Now to the question, i'm looking for a design pattern or general design ideas that fits such production-manufacturing lines, specifically ones with moving robot arms and time limitation constraints.

im sure im not the first to write such a production line manager so i hope to use the wisdom of the community in this matter.

Adiel.

p.s. i hope the general information i provided is enough to describe the problem, if not i'll be happy to add information.

[image: An illustration of the machine - the robot is the center of the chamber]

Comment: So you have a series of robots, each that moves product between a pair of staions?  Or one robot that moves the product down a line of stations?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon what you wrote, you are in the space of 'behavoural' design patterns.  And within that space, if you have a number of operations that must be performed in a predefined sequence, then you would consider the Chain of Responsibility pattern.

*...the chain-of-responsibility pattern is a design pattern consisting of a source of command objects and a series of processing objects. Each processing object contains logic that defines the types of command objects that it can handle; the rest are passed to the next processing object in the chain.  A mechanism also exists for adding new processing objects to the end of this chain.*

Source:  [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Secondarily, the publish/subscribe pattern would be used to provide notifications between your various components.

Comment: Thanks. the publish/subscribe is already in use it is part of our machine building framework. Now, regrading the COR pattern i find it hard to see how can i use it here. First, the product has to go through each of the stations (with no exception). Second, each station by itself only knows about its occupied bins and its passive  , the robot is the one who set the tone here. The managment here is more central. i think COR is more suitable for when you want decentralized decentralized the management and control.

Comment: It's based upon what you wrote originally, prior to the editing.  The opportunity to embed a series of commands which can be operated upon without reference to their origin.  I can see you have also added a graphic, but the labels are off page.